# Can you install Windows as a dual-boot on a computer with only Linux installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot

I was thinking about buying the Galago Pro 13" from System76 when it comes out, I think it'd be a great Linux laptop. However, in the future, I could see myself potentially needing to use Windows 10 (**not WiNE**) in a dual-boot with Ubuntu. Is this possible?

Comment: it works. have a look for example here: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-install-linux-windows-machine-uefi-secure-boot

Comment: No, I' have a computer that comes with Linux and not Windows.

Comment: [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](//askubuntu.com/q/6317)

Comment: DavidPostill Submit that as an answer!

Comment: @KeeganKuhn Done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is this possible?

Yes. See [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/6321/376050) on Ask Ubuntu from [evgeny](https://askubuntu.com/users/2804/evgeny):

> Here's the general outline:
>
> 1. Make space for Windows
> 2. Install Windows
> 3. Mount the `/boot` direcory or partition
> 4. Install the bootloader ([GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB))
>
> ## Step One – Make space for Windows
>
> Open up [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted), and make sure that you have at least 20 GB
>   available for Windows 7, either as a partition you can remove, or as
>   unpartitioned space. If it's a partition, remove it from GRUB to make
>   sure it doesn't break your Ubuntu install — GParted will complain if
>   anything bad is about to happen.
>
> *Make note of current `/boot` device. If that doesn't show up there, make note of the `/` device. The device name is something like
>   `sda5`*.
>
> ## Step Two – Install Windows
>
> Install Windows 7 into the space you just made
>
> ## Step Three – Mount `/boot`
>
> > <sub>Note: Instead of mounting the boot directory or partition from the installation in the live media environment you can specify the
> >     path with the `--boot-directory` parameter for grub-install, more
> >     information on the manpage.</sub>
>
> Load up from your [Ubuntu live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD), and then run these commands.
>
> - If you DO NOT have a separate `/boot` partition:
>
>   ```
>   sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /mnt
>   sudo rm -rf /boot    # Careful here, make sure YOU ARE USING THE LIVE CD. I tried it, it works.
>   sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot
>   ```
> - If you have a SEPARATE `/boot` partition:
>
>   ```
>   sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /boot
>   ```
>
> ## Step Four – Install the bootloader
>
> > <sub>Note: These instructions were initially written for Windows 7 and BIOS booting computers. If you have UEFI and Windows 8 and above
> >     you probably need to replace `grub-pc` with `grub-efi-amd64` in `sudo
> >     apt-get install grub-pc`.</sub>
>
> Then continue with those commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install grub-pc
> sudo grub-install /dev/sda     # NOTE THAT THERE IS NO DIGIT
> sudo umount /boot
> ```
>
> And restart. It should work fine and boot both systems.